# Composite operations in Android Canvas

Tags: java, android, html5-canvas, android-canvas

I'm just starting with Android development and I'm coming from JavaScript/HTML world so I'm currently investigating the possibilities of the Android SDK.

The HTML 5 canvas supports composite operations (See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Compositing)).

Is this possible in an Android Canvas? I scanned the API of the Canvas class but couldn't find anything useful. I need at least the composite operation "source-in" or (if this isn't possible) "source-atop".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Composition is handled by drawing on a `Canvas` with a `Paint` that uses a `PorterDuffXfermode`.

```
Paint p=new Paint();
p.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN));
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, p);
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763572/override-ondraw-to-change-how-the-drawing-occurs-android) for more info. I also managed to override `onPaint` so that we can apply this composition to elements that draw themeselves.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked into doing those kinds of operations before, but I think there's a way to do them using the [Rect](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html) shape. You can define rectangles to mark out which areas should be drawn into the canvas, or which to take out of the source image, and the `Rect` class has some comparison features built-in. For example to imitate a source-in, you could use `setIntersect(Rect boundingBoxOfSource, Rect boundingBoxOfDestination)` to make your new rectangle only have the intersected area of the two images. Then you can use that rectangle as an argument in one of the Canvas's draw commands, telling it to only take the pixels from the source image that are inside that rectangle. You then control the drawing in the Z-axis by the order in which the draw commands are executed.

Comment: Simple clipping with rectangles is not enough. I need complex alpha masks.

Comment: I was just going on the two example images shown in your link - the source-in and source-atop examples didn't appear to have any alpha-masking. If that's what you're after, offhand I don't know how to do it. Canvases do support transparency between 'layers' of images drawn on top of each other provided the images already have that transparency built-in, but someone more experienced will have to tell us whether it's possible to do the blending automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Found it myself. The PorterDuffXfermode implements all these composite modes.