# android webview offscreen rendering

Tags: android, android-webview

is it possible to intercept and apply some custom effects/color correction before android webview's gets rendered on the screen. I want the web-view to stay responsive to touch interactions after applying the effects.

Comment: yes.. possible you have to inject your javascript file to the rendering page..

Comment: @user1992200 can you please elaborate a bit with a link if available?

Comment: refer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21552912/android-web-view-inject-local-javascript-file-to-remote-webpage  in the local script file should contain the java script code to modify the corrections

Comment: you can also use view.loadUrl("javascript:" +"function{  //your code };")  ..

Comment: what i want to do is apply some sort of custom image processing effect to whatever is rendered on the webview

Comment: custom image processing means ?..  modifying properties of dom elements.. ?

Comment: something like this http://www.felixjones.co.uk/neo%20website/Android_View/ but with all the touch interactions

Comment: no it could not be done with js injection .. i think  the link you provided is purely based on presenting webviews in 3d ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inherit your class from `WebView`, override `OnDraw` method. See this answer for an example: [Override onDraw to change how the drawing occurs (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763572/override-ondraw-to-change-how-the-drawing-occurs-android)

Comment: that was my first guess but somewhere on here i read onDraw wont be of much help and that completely dissuaded me from trying it..i will try it tomorrow and let you know how it works.

Comment: Sorry for that! Drawing an html page is already an expensive task, so adding extra image processing without slowing everything down is not trivial.